# Why am I seeing a red icon instead of a json icon on the left corner on VS Code?

Tags: json, visual-studio

[image]

When I try to run this code it says code language is not supported even though I have set it to JSON. I keep getting this error. How to fix??

Answer (score 0):

JSON (JavaScript Object Notation) is just a file format that is used to exchange data from servers. It is not a programming language that you can run. The file package.json is used mainly for configuration with package managers.